# Javascript: giving each object in array a setInterval on one of its methods

Tags: javascript

new to javascript.

I have a a custom defined object with a method update. I have an array of the objects.

```
  function update_all(objects){
    for (var i = 0 ; i < objects.length; i++){
       var obj = objects[i];
       var repeater = setInterval(function () {obj.update();}, 1000);
    }
  }
```

curiously, only the last object of the array get a setinterval for the objects update method. Also all the setintervals point to the last object of the array. So for example if there are 4 objects, the last object updates 4 times a second, the others not at all. what's going on?

thanks

Comment: Just FYI, it's faster to work out `objects.length` before the loop, as it is recalculated on each iteration if called during the loop's creation.

Comment: You have to use closures to pass the data to the inner function, DEMO at http://jsfiddle.net/M4Xkh/1/

Comment: @Grim... no it's not.

Comment: @Benjamin, maybe Grim's statement could be rephrased like so to prevent arguments: "...`objects.length` before the loop, as it might be *evaluated* on each iteration depending on the JavaScript interpreter"

Comment: Indeed. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: @chiccodoro yeah I guess it _might_, but it really really really really won't, promise. Technically an interperter could do `Thread.Sleep(1000)` every time an object length is accessed but none do. Caching `array.length` is not faster in any JavaScript interperter from the last few years and it just adds clutter. On the other hand, caching the lengths of DOM `NodeList`s is important (this is a rather common misconception) as `NodeList`s are live - this means that if you get elements with `getElementsByTagName` and append new elements with that tag name in the loop you get an infinite loop. Fun

Comment: @Benjamin - I see. +1 for the lesson learnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, a for loop does not open a new scope for variables. Your `obj` variable has at least function scope (if your code is in a function, or otherwise global scope). That is, each iteration through the for loop in fact *changes* the value of the single `obj` variable in the function. When you leave the for loop, you end up with a lot of timers, but they all call update on the same object.

To prevent that you need to extract your loop body into another function so as to create a new scope for each iteration. Alongside with some other recommendations, it could look like this:

```
var i, n;

for (i = 0, n = objects.length; i < n; i++) {
    createIntervalToCallUpdate(objects[i]);
}
```

And your function:

```
function createIntervalToCallUpdate(objectToUpdate) {
    var repeater = setInterval(function () { objectToUpdate.update(); }, 1000);
}
```

To get more understanding on this, read about a concept called "hoisting", for example in this [article about scoping and hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html). Hoisting is also a reason why many recommend to declare all your variables at the top of the function. If you declared `obj` at the top of your function (which implies, outside the for loop), you wouldn't be trapped into believing that the variable could be redefined for each iteration.

**Update:** Philipp's suggestion is great as it makes the code simpler and easier to read (given that your browser supports `array.forEach` which is rather new). It basically does exactly what the code above does, except it already does the task of the first snippet for you.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `obj` has the same scope for all iterations. You could fix that problem by replacing your for-loop with the [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function.

```
 objects.forEach( function(obj) {
      setInterval(function () {obj.update();}, 1000);
 });
```

The forEach function calls the declared function once for each entry in the array. The anonymous function defines a closure in which each `obj` represents a different instance.

Comment: +1, this is the prefered and simplest approach. `objects.forEach(setInterval.bind(null,obj.update.bind(obj),1000))` if you're into a more functional style

Comment: does forEach supports ie8

Comment: @Basha Not by default, but there is a polyfill under the link I posted in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I think we should use this approach in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing has to do with closures. The variable `obj` is not only accesible inside the `for`-loop, which means that when the callback of your `setInterval` is executed, it will the last reference of `obj` that is availible - in this case the last object in the array.

To fix this problem, you could try using the built-in function `forEach` in combinaion with a function for setting the interval:

```
function setObjectInterval( obj ) {
    setInterval(function () {obj.update();}, 1000);
}

objects.forEach( function( obj ) {
    setObjectInterval( obj );
} );
```