# Three.js: Looking to spawn objects and animate the objects on a curve

Tags: javascript, animation, 3d, three.js, curve

I am trying to spawn a set of objects on a setInterval and give each of these objects their own animation on a path (currently using requestAnimationFrame to do so). I managed to add one object and animate this on a path. With this code:

```
var psGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3,2,10,1);
var psPlane = new THREE.Mesh(psGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x0000ff}));
scene.add(psPlane);

function animatePaper(obj = psPlane, offset= 0.007)
{
    if(counter <=( 1-obj.geometry.vertices.length/2 *offset))
    {
        for (var i=0; i < obj.geometry.vertices.length/2; i++)
        {
            obj.geometry.vertices[i].y = curvePath.getPoint(counter + i * offset).y;
            obj.geometry.vertices[i].z = -0.5;
            obj.geometry.vertices[i + obj.geometry.vertices.length/2].y = curvePath.getPoint(counter + i * offset).y;
            obj.geometry.vertices[i + obj.geometry.vertices.length/2].z = -2.5;

            obj.geometry.vertices[i].x = curvePath.getPoint(counter + i * offset).x;
            obj.geometry.vertices[i + obj.geometry.vertices.length/2].x = curvePath.getPoint(counter + i * offset).x;

        }
        obj.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

        counter += 0.005;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Removing...");
        scene.remove(obj);
    }
}
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    animatePaper(psPlane, 0.007);
    render();
}
```

Example can be found here: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/mf6dzhrf/2/).

Since this animates the object along the curvePath (see jsfiddle example), I figured that spawning these objects on an interval and applying the above code should work. Wrong!.

**I tried:** creating a function spawning objects and applying the above code:

```
setInterval(drawSheets, 1000); 
function drawSheets()
{
    var psGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3,2,10,1);
    var psPlane = new THREE.Mesh(psGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x0000ff}));
    scene.add(psPlane);
    setInterval(function(){animatePaper(psPlane, 0.007);}, 30);
}
```

I also tried on the basis of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754354/javascript-giving-each-object-in-array-a-setinterval-on-one-of-its-methods):

```
setInterval(objArray.forEach(function(obj){setInterval(function(){animatePaper(obj);},300);}), 3000);
```

**Expected:**
Spawning multiple objects on an interval and animate each of these objects seperately over a curve.

Hopefully anyone could help me out! Cheers.

Version: Three.js r82

** EDIT: ** Small refinement. After another small test ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j6qpc92/1/)). I found out that when I use setInterval on a function, it shares the same variable (thus speeding up the animation). Since this is part of the problem I would like to ask if someone knows how to make these variables local to an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating an array containing each of your Path and Plane objects (or perhaps one array for Paths and one array for Planes) along with their distinctive offsets or other values, then loop though these in an update function in your animation loop, running each through your `animatePaper` function.

**In pseudo code:**

```
var planesAndMeshesArray = [ 
    { path1 : (your plane here), plane1 : (your curved mesh here), offset : (an offset value), extrudeSettings : (your settings object here) }, 
    { path2 : (your plane here), plane2 : (your curved mesh here), offset : (an offset value), extrudeSettings : (your settings object here) }, 
    { path3 : (your plane here), plane3 : (your curved mesh here), offset : (an offset value), extrudeSettings : (your settings object here) },
...]

- create a loop to write the above array with random values in an appropriate range to suit the effects you're looking for
- loop through the above array to add each of the meshes and planes to the scene     

function update() {
    - update each object by looping through the above array through your `animatePaper` function. It works as a handy set of pointers to each of the objects in your scene - if you change them in the array, they will change in your scene. 
    - also update your controls
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    update();
    render();
}
```

Going one step further, you can write [object-oriented Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter8.html) to create each of your curve-and-paper objects. I'd recommend starting with the array first and adding further complexity as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! With your input I managed to get it working. Working example:[link](https://jsfiddle.net/x7jp5ojd/5/).

Comment: @Yannickd - Congrats, looks great! You can even keep them going continuously by adding new ones  periodically to the array as you loop. :)